# Выравнивание элементов из разных дивов

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Нужно выровнять блоки из разных дивов относительно друг друга в номерном порядке. Я ищу какое-то свойство, вроде `order-group`(<-- придуманное свойство), или что-то такое, чтобы можно было определить, к какой именно группе выравнивания элемент относится, и выровнять этот элемент относительно других элементов группы с помощью свойства order. 
Существует ли такое свойство, и если да, как оно называется?

Comment: Выложите пример вашего кода пожалуйста, display:flex обычно и подразумевает под собой "order-group"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Флексбокс позволяет использовать `order`, а ещё в css есть (с сомнительной поддержкой) [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/display). Совмещаем и, теоретически, должно работать:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="order:1">A1</div>
  <div style="order:2">A2</div>
  <div style="order:3">A3</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div style="order:1">B1</div>
  <div style="order:2">B2</div>
  <div style="order:3">B3</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div style="order:1">C1</div>
  <div style="order:2">C2</div>
  <div style="order:3">C3</div>
</section>
```

Собственно, в FF58 действительно работает:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: 5.41% глобальной поддержки, маловато однако, но решение мне понравилось

Comment: Ну хром тоже что-то пилит... Но вообще да, пока маловато. Не думаю, что на css можно придумать что-то лучше для перемешивания блоков из разных контейнеров.